# How can I align image to the top right in html

Tags: html

i want to align image to the top right how can i do it in html.
Here's my code:

```
<img src="star.png" alt="Gold" align="right">
```

I don't want to align it to right. I want to align it on the top right corner.

Answer (score 3):

You can make its position absolute and apply `right:0` and `top:0`:

```css
img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Gold" align="right">
```

Comment: I would do this as well - jsut note that the parent container of the img needs to have position: relative in its styling - otherwise the position of the image will be based on the first ancstor that has position: relative in its styling. That can lead to funky results

Answer (score 0):

For better practice use the position on the div and the images inside it.
Html be like

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="star.png" alt="Gold">
</div>
```

Css be like

```
<style>
.images{

  position:relative;

}
.images img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
</style>
```